# Why is parallelism bad in execution plans

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

People seem to hint that when the yellow arrows appear in the execution plan it is a bad sign. Why is it a problem that a query runs in parallel?

Comment: Your SQL server does need to do some extra work before getting the results back to you, as described [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5404/parallelism-in-sql-server-execution-plan/).

Comment: *"People seem to hint that when the yellow arrows appear in the execution plan it is a bad sign*" Where? Who are these "people"? Is this something a colleague said to you? If so, when you asked them about it what reasoning did they give>? If you read this in multiple articles, what were these articles/answers? Please cite and quote the sources.

Comment: @Larnu: Hi it is just the tone, I have not heard directly that parallelism is "bad", but the tone. It is something I have infered from the tone. Also e.g. sp_BlitzChace has "Parallel" as a warning...

Comment: @David there's a article on that: [sp_BlitzCache™ Result: Parallel Plans Detected](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/parallel-plans-detected/). Notice the first thing it says, however, is *"This isn’t necessarily a bad thing"*; hence why it's a warning. You need to be aware there is parallelism but that doesn't mean you should get rid of it or even that it's detrimental.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bad sign. Depending on certain settings the engine may decide to use parallel operators in order to optimize the execution of certain T-SQL statements. In most of the cases it will make the better choice (either to use or not to use).

If you are worried about the engine not taking the better decision you can change the `Max Degree of Parallelism` and `Cost Threshold For Parallelism`. Anyway, there are [hints](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4939/how-to-force-a-parallel-execution-plan-in-sql-server-2016/) to force the parallel execution, too - [Forced Parameterization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#ForcedParam).

I personally, have tried forcing parallel operations and denying them in order to debug/improve performance but in the end I always leave it to the engine to make these decisions instead of me.